# Iterating over list in event processing

Tags: esper, cumulocity

I am currently trying to iterate over a list of ManagedObjects in event processing through a script.
It should check a condition for each `ManagedObject` in the list and once it is true return that Object.

This is my script:

```
 create expression ManagedObject getCurrentDepot(position, listObjects) [ 
     for (i = 0; i <= listObjects.length; i++) { 
         var obj = listObjects[i]; 
         var distance = distance(position.lat, position.lng, obj.Geofence.lat, obj.Geofence.lng); 
         if (distance <= obj.radius ) { 
             depot; 
         } 
     } 
     null; 
 ];
```

I get the following error:

> Error in statement mytest:statement_2! : Incorrect syntax near ';' at line 3 column 26

It complains about this line:

```
var obj = listObjects[i];
```

How can I correctly iterate over the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to not do the looping in the expression but in the event processing itself.

```
create expression Boolean isInRange(position, element) [
     var distance = distance(position.lat, position.lng, element.Geofence.lat, obj.Geofence.lng); 
     if (distance <= element.radius ) { 
         true; 
     }
     false;
 ];

insert into MyStreamWithDepot
select
    event.listObjects.firstOf(element => isInRange(event.position, element) is true) as currentDepot
from InputEvent event;
```

You can have a look at the documentation for the "firstOf" method here [esper documentation](http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#enumeration-method-firstof)

Comment: But this is going to take only the first element that satisfy the condition, isn't ? What about if other element also satisfies the condition?

Comment: Yes correct firstOf will only return the first match. Maybe check takeWhile() function. It might suit your need.

Comment: Taking in consideration the takeWhile() you mention and follow the example you wrote, every time the takeWhile() return a value the MyStreamWithDepot stream is going to be trigger or will be trigger just once with all events that apply to the condition inside the takeWhile()?

Comment: Maybe you should move that into an own question as this has nothing to do with the question here. I have never used it but it looks like it returns a collection

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var distance;
listObjects.forEach(function(obj) {          
        distance  = distance(position.lat, position.lng, obj.Geofence.lat, obj.Geofence.lng); 
         if (distance <= obj.radius ) { 
             depot; 
         } 
     });
```